Why does synchronize_session="fetch" work with SQLAlchemy Query API and not CORE?
I wrote a query in SQLAlchemy (Postgresql) that was a simple update however it was using a cast on one of the where conditions like so:
stmt = (
   update(MyModel).
   where(
     func.cast(MyModel.last_mod, Date) == current_week_minus_one,
     MyModel.deleted.is_(False)
   ).
   values(
      deleted=True,
      notification_s=True
   )
session.execute(stmt)
session.commit()
 

However this kept throwing me the error:
"Cannot evaluate Cast". Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session execution option
So I put the synchronize_session="fetch" in the execute statement like so:
session.execute(stmt, synchronize_session="fetch") 

However I still had the same error. I then looked at this SO post, and the answer was resolving it using the Query API not SQLAlchemy CORE. So I changed my code to this:
stmt = (
   session.query(MyModel).
   filter(
     func.cast(MyModel.last_mod, Date) == current_week_minus_one,
     MyModel.deleted.is_(False)
   ).
   update(
      {MyModel.deleted: True,
      MyModel.notification_s:True},
     synchronize_session="fetch"

   )
session.commit()
 

Now it works, but I am not clear as why I cannot do this using SQLALchemy CORE.

In SQLAlchemy 2.0+, the synchronisation method is passed as an execution option to Session.execute:
session.execute(stmt, execution_options={'synchronize_session': 'fetch'})

Note that while SQLAlchemy 2.0 query syntax is the more or less the same for the ORM or Core layers, sessions are part of the ORM layer only.
